# Javascript Calculation not working - shows NaN, Infinity or nothing at all

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to get this calculation to work but am struggling at the minute. The answer either comes up with NaN, Infinity or it doesn't show an answer at all. Not sure where i'm going wrong. Any help greatly appreciated. The calculation I'm looking to achieve is (mybox1/mybox2-(mybox3/100))*20

https://jsfiddle.net/kosw1mzn/

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<input id="box1" type= "number">
<input id="box2" type= "number">
<input id="box3" type= "number">
<input id="box4" type= "number">
<input id="display" readonly>

<script>
function calculate()
{
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
    var myBox4 = document.getElementById('box4').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('display');
    var myResult = ((myBox1/myBox2-(myBox3/100))*20);
    result.value = myResult;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be aware that `.value()` will always return a string.

Comment: where you call `calculate`?

Comment: if `myBox2`'s value is 0 you cannot divide by it. also you will need to use `parseInt` on your values

Comment: works fine for me, of course if you fill all the input fields: https://jsfiddle.net/kosw1mzn/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot divide by 0 without it returning `+-Infinity` (`x/0` where x !== 0) or `NaN` (`0/0`), so set defaults for your values if the `parseInt` result is not a number.

I have added a parseElementValue function to save repeating myself.

Updated to include request for rounding to 2 decimal places and to set result input value to empty on start

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kosw1mzn/7/)**

```
var result = document.getElementById('display');
function calculate()
{
    var myBox1 = parseElementValue(document.getElementById('box1').value);
    var myBox2 = parseElementValue(document.getElementById('box2').value);
    var myBox3 = parseElementValue(document.getElementById('box3').value);
    var myBox4 = parseElementValue(document.getElementById('box4').value);
    var myResult = 0;
    if(myBox2 > 0){
        myResult = ((myBox1/myBox2-(myBox3/100))*20);
    }
    result.value = myResult.toFixed(2);
}

function parseElementValue(value){
    return parseInt(value, 10) || 0;
}
result.value = '';
```

Thanks to Grundy in the comments for the clarification around `Infinity` vs `NaN` returned 0 denominator division

Comment: you **can** divide by 0 withou creating a `NaN` for example: `1/0` return _Infinity_

Comment: @Grundy, apologies, you are correct, i have updated my answer

Comment: but `0/0` really return _NaN_ :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Two questions 1. how can i round to two decimal places and 2. the display box in the browsers shows NaN until the calculate button is pressed. how can i show nothing until the button is clicked?

Comment: @C.Hopewell, you can use `result.value = myResult.toFixed(2)` to round to 2 decimal places, im not exereincing the `NaN` until calculate is pressed in OSX Chrome in my fiddle, but have updated my code to try to combat what you're seeing

Comment: @haxxxton, in my fiddle it didn't show NaN either however when i add code back into dreamweaver and load the file my desktop it shows up. Will try and change code to stop it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function calculate()
{
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
    var myBox4 = document.getElementById('box4').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('display');
    var myResult = ((+myBox1/(+myBox2 || 1)-(+myBox3/100))*20);
    result.value = myResult;
}
```

Used [Unary +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) to convert string to number. Division by 0 is guarded by [OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) 1.

**Update:**

Fiddle updated to round result to 2 decimal places.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/kosw1mzn/8/

Answer (score -2):

I'm checking your example and seems it returns correct result. I'm adding button to process calculation

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kosw1mzn/2/

Please clarify what problem you are facing?